# .net gridview destroying jqwidgets window

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, jqwidget

I'm in the midst of transforming an older site from pure ASP.Net to some ASP.Net with some JQWidgets and ajax calls.

If I 'open' a jqwidgets window from a template column in a .net gridview, the window flashes for about a half a second and is then destroyed.  Trying to figure out what is destroying the window.

If I put the logic outside of the gridview, the JQWidget window performs as expected, so I know I have the logic working.

I'm guessing that the GridView has some client side script which destroys any dom objects after the executed javascript is completed on the template column.  If this assumption is correct, can I intercept and tell it to not destroy?

If this assumption is wrong, any idea on what might be causing it?

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Comment: Did you try search about `JQWidget` and `GridView` compatibility? and what kind of `ajax` controls/templates you're using? Please add source code in your question.